# Sending Push Notification & APNS handshake

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I want to understand the Push Notification process both for test & production environment. We maintain 2 different certificates to handshake between our server & APNS; one for test & another for production.

1. Are there 2 APNS or just one with multiple handshake certificates?
2. How is the client build gets signed with appropriate certificate to get push from right APNS?

Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think there are actually two APNS, one called sandbox for development test purpose, another for productive system
2. it's about provision. You setup certificate with Apps, bundle Apps with provisions, and release your app with provisions (either development, ad-hoc or App Store)

With test/development certificate, it seems that only developers' devices can receive pushed notifications from Apple. With production certificate client device can receive pushed notification either through ad-hoc distribution or App Store distribution.